# Make SearchView text entry disabled?

Tags: java, android, searchview

I was wondering if there was a way to temporarily make it so that SearchView temporarily cannot be used to type in but still seen. I'd rather do this than recreate different actionbars over and over for the same activity.

UPDATE:
neither answer worked here is stacktrace:

```
05-08 18:51:38.981  18963-18963/com.parse.starter W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
05-08 18:51:38.989  18963-18963/com.parse.starter W/ImageView﹕ Unable to find resource: 1
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:663)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:647)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1181)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:848)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2267)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1074)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2462)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4558)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you want to set TextView of SearchView disabled?

Comment: No, the actual SearchView itself

Comment: Not sure still why log cat showed that but I fixed it by deleting application modules gen folder and rebuilding my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily enable and disable your menu items in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.
Just simply get your searchView and put `setEnabled(false)`, like this:

```
MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
item.setEnabled(false);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I eventually got it to work by changing it a little because the SearchView was used in two different class I just returned super.oncreate...(menu) In my Boolean method of my activity and in the other class I just used menu.finditem.... Without reinflating the ActionBar layout because that resulted in two SearchView icons.

Comment: That's Good.If you need more information about Actionbar then,read about action bar from this link.
"http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html"
This will help you much.

Answer (score 2):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

For value 0x00000000 - there is no content type. The text is not editable.

So try this:

```
mSearchView.setInputType(0x00000000);
```

and to switch back to editable:

```
mSearchView.setInputType(0x00000001);
```